# Deciding between use of foldleft() or Seq.newBuilder in Scala

Tags: scala, seq, foldleft

I have some code where I need to add elements to a sequence while iterating over another one. Which way is the 'preferred' or rather the better way of doing that in scala and why?:

Way 1:

```
val builder = Seq.newBuilder[String]    
for(i <- iterator){
builder += i  //Everytime I want to add a new element    
}
```

Way 2:

```
val stringSeq = iterator.foldLeft(Seq[String]()){
case (acc, i) => i +: acc
}
```

Comment: In your `Way 1` you want the builder to be outside the loop. Also you should add `i` to the builder (not `"Element"`) to match your `Way 2` code.

Comment: @Kigyo You are correct. Silly me.

Comment: 2 more annoying things. There is a `-` missing: `for(i <- iterator)` and `foldLeft` (capital L).

Comment: Why not map/flatMap on the iterator to get a new sequence that has what you want (Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do... )

Comment: Can you explain your use case? I would do neither of these, but use yield to get the sequence directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say *Way 2* is more idiomatic and feels more functional, as you do not create mutable state.

The *Way 1* seems to be a bit more imperative, as it resembles `for` as it is used in the object oriented programming.

However Scala has both OOP elements and FP elements. I guess you should use a construct, which works better for you, due to for example performance reasons (however I don't think your example is the case, as appending to the head of `Seq` should be fast).

PS. your generator should be `<-` not `<` and it is `foldLeft` (capital *L*)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use both, and be both functional and efficient?

```
iterator.foldLeft(Seq.newBuilder[String])(_ += _).result
```

Note that this code's behaviour is slightly different than that of your second solution: your solution reverse the iterator's order, mine preserves it. I don't know which is desired.

Also, just in case it didn't occur to you (sorry if I'm being obvious), any particular reason you're not using `iterator.toSeq`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `++:` method in `Seq`, so you can just do `seq ++: iterator`

And don't worry about performance, it's a basic API scala provide us and we should trust it.

Actually the current implementation is similar to your way 1.